# Second-Order Optimality Measure in Matlab

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, hessian-matrix

Is there any code for the second-order optimality measure in constrained optimization in Matlab? More precisely, I am using `fmincon`, and I want to find the bordered Hessian matrix. Is there any way in Matlab to calculate the bordered Hessian matrix at the optimum point?

Answer (score 1):

fmincon does not currently do what you want.  What you need can be computed as shown below.

hessian can be included as the last output argument in a call to fmincon.  As documented at https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/hessian.html , the returned hessian is the Hessian of the Lagrangian at the "optimum" point.

The 2nd order optimum condition is that the Hessian of the Lagrangian projected into the nullspace of the Jacobian of active constraints is symmetric positive semidefinite (psd).

First find all the active linear and nonlinear constraints (i.e., all equalities and those inequalities (including bound constraints) satisfied with equality to within numerical tolerance). Then caclulate the Jacobian matrix of these active constraints, call it J. Then calculate a basis for the nullspace of J as `Z = null(J)` .   The Hessian of the Lagrangian projected into the nullspace of the Jacobian of active constraints is then `Z' * hessian * Z`, which should be assessed for positive semidefiniteness.  Note that if hessian (i.e., the Hessian of the Lagrangian) is psd, you can conclude that its projection into the nullspace of the Jacobian of active constraints must be psd, even without performing the projection; however, the projection might be psd when the unprojected hessian is not.

Comment: thank you veeeery much for your guidance. So you are telling that in Mathlab I cant find a command for that?I mean outside fmincon can I find any command for that?
would you please tell one good reference to understand your last paragraph better. to be honest I dont exactly now nullspace and ...

Comment: fmincon doesn't do it, but it could be potentially added in some future version. The biggest danger of getting a declaration of 1st order optimum that really isn't local optimum is on the initial iteration if the 1st order KKT conditions are satisfied, in which case fmincon reports local optimum. After that, it isn't likely due to the algorithm "rolling downhill", although it's possible it might end on a saddle point. Some 3rd party optimizers under MATLAB might have a 2nd order optimum test, but I don;t know of any publlicy available ones.  Jacobian is matrix of constraint gradients.

Comment: You don't need to understand nullspace. Just use the commands I provided once you compute Jacobian (matrix of gradients) of active constraints. I found some "references" for 2nd order optimum conditions by googling, http://www.math.ucla.edu/~lvese/273.1.06f/Summary.pdf and https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_06/Chapter2.pdf .

Comment: For Jacobian, extract all rows from Aeq, extract the rows from Aineq which are satisfied with (approximate) equality at current point, and extract (and transpose) from nonlcon the gradients of nonlinear equality constraints and gradients of nonlinear inequality constraints satisfied with (approximate) equality at current point. Put all that in one big matrix, and that is the Jacobian of active constraints. This is more numerically stable way of doing things than using bordered Hessians (I haven't used them since I did Economics as an undergrad before learning the good stuff).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try and come back if there is any problem!

Comment: Dear Mark
I couldn't do what you told. would you please write an example for what you told?

Comment: "the 'hessian' returned by fmincon is not a hessian" slide 19 of http://ice.uchicago.edu/2009_presentations/Skrainka_OptHessians.pdf

Comment: @Parker Lusk What slide 19 says applies only if the BFGS option of FMINCON s used. Actually, the situation for BFGS is even worse than described there, because the BFGS Hessian will always be positive semidefinite, which renders the 2nd order optimality test meaningless. However, FMINCON can be used with user-supplied Hessian, in which case the 2nd order optimality conditions I described are valid and meaningful.